# How to Add Time and Status Feature to To-Do List Script

Tags: python, python-3.x

Started seriously getting into python this week (it's the first language I'm planning to learn), and I wrote this to-do list script today. I implemented add, remove and view features, but now I want to be able to add the time something is due by, and mark if it is done. How can I do this? Thanks in advance! Code is below.

```
list = []

def add():
    global itemadd
    itemadd = input("What would you like to add?")
    list.append(itemadd)
    print("You've added " + itemadd + " to your to-do list. Here is what your list currently looks like:")
    print(list)

def remove():
    print(list)
    global itemremove
    itemremove = input("What would you like to remove?")
    if itemremove in list:
      list.remove(itemremove)
    else:
      while itemremove not in list:
        print("This item is not on your to-do list. Did you spell it correctly?")
        itemremove = input("Try again:")
    print("You have removed " + itemremove + " from your to-do list. Here is what your list currently looks like:")
    print(list)


def prompt():
    ask = input("What would you like to do? (add an item (add), view list (view), remove an item (remove))")

    if ask == "add":
        add()
    elif ask == "view":
        print("Here is your to-do list:")
        print(list)
    elif ask == "remove":
        remove()

stop = False

while not stop:
  prompt()
```

Comment: Your question is very broad as there are many possible ways to implement the functionality you're proposing.

Answer (score 0):

You could create a class to record every thing that needs to be done, and another to hold the things to do:

```
class ThingToDo:
    def __init__(self, thing, date, status):
        self.thing = thing
        self.date = date
        self.status = status
    ...

class ListOfThingsToDo:
    def __init__(self):
        self.things_to_do = []
        ...
```

Then implement your `add_thing`, `remove_thing`, `update_status`, `archive_thing`, `reprogram_thing`, etc., methods

Comment: Thanks! This is a bit too advanced for me right now, but I plan on looking into it soon. I've started trying to do this with dictionaries.